# Connecting it with Ngmodel using nested objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

person.model.ts page;

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    desc: string;
    adres: Address;
}

export class Address {
    city: string;
    disticy: string;
    postCode: number;
    country: string;
}
```

person.component.html page;

```html
...

<div class="bg-secondary container"> {{ jsonPerson }} </div>

...

<input [(ngModel)]="newPerson.adres.city" name="city" type="text" id="city" placeholder="Şehir" class="form-control">

...
```

form.component.ts page;

```js
...

public newPerson: Person = new Person();

get jsonPerson() {
  return JSON.stringify(this.newPerson) 
}

...
```

The problem is; I want to use my address information as an object. And this is how I used it. But when I bind to my html page as [(ngModel)]="newPerson.address.city" I get an error. That is, how can I reach the Address object inside the Person object and get a successful output.

Information: person.model.ts is not my data source. I distribute my data to the necessary pages via person.service.ts. so there is no database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize it.

```
export class Person {
    adres: Address = new Address();
}
```

or

```
export class Person {
    adres: Address;
    constructor() {
      this.adres = new Address();
    }
}
```

Comment: teşekkür ederim

Comment: if you find this useful, please approve it by clicking on the check button near the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

@Furkan just keep in mind that:

> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in a future version of Angular.

Now deprecated:
`<input [formControl]="control" [(ngModel)]="value">`

https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#ngmodel-reactive

Comment: I am not very experienced. This information will be very useful for me at the learning stage. ty